# Jquery JSON parsing with @id:

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "@id": "hey there",
    "id": "hey there 2"
}
```

I can easily parse `"id"` with `json.id` but how can I get the value of `"@id"` using jquery's inbuilt JSON parser?

As calling `"json.@id"` is not correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
json['@id']
```

Also note that the JSON object you've posted is not valid: you are missing a `,` between the two properties.

Comment: you ve been providing all the answers for questions related to json for me and other users also.. So +1

Comment: Obviously. Sigh. One of those days. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above answer, you can use http://jsonlint.com to validate your json

Comment: I don't really see how that's relevant.

Comment: Yes, but the question was not if the JSON is valid or not, but how to access properties with names that are not valid identifiers.

Comment: @Dave Van den Eynde Sigh - Note the "In additon to the above" bit